# How do I track NSError objects across threads?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, error-handling, nserror

I have a set of asynchronous calls being spawned using `NSInvocationOperation`:

```
- (void)listRequestQueue:(StoreDataListRequest *)request {
    [openListRequests addObject:request];

    NSInvocationOperation *requestOp = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                        initWithTarget:self
                                        selector:@selector(listRequestStart:)
                                        object:request];
    [opQueue addOperation:requestOp];
    [requestOp release];
}

- (void)listRequestStart:(StoreDataListRequest *)request {
    if(self.resourceData == nil) {
        //TODO fail appropriately...
        return;
    }

    StoreDataListResponse *response = [self newListResponseForProductID:request.productID];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(listRequestFinish:)
                           withObject:response waitUntilDone:NO];
    [response release];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(cleanUpListRequest:)
                           withObject:request waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void)listRequestFinish:(StoreDataListResponse *)response {
    [self.delegate storeData:self didReceiveListResponse:response];
}

- (StoreDataListResponse *)newListResponseForProductID:(NSString *)productID {
    CollectionData *data = [self.resourceData dataForProduct:productID];
    if(data == nil) {
        //TODO do something
    }

    StoreDataListResponse *response = [[StoreDataListResponse alloc] init];
    response.productID = productID;
    if(productID != data.productID) {
        //TODO fail; remove product from list
    }
    response.name = NSLocalizedString(@"Loading...", @"Loading message");
    response.blurb = NSLocalizedString(@"Waiting for response from server", @"Waiting for website to respond");
    return response;
}
```

For each of the `TODO`s in the above code, I should resolve the issue and let any handlers know that things have failed and why. Looking at the `NSError` class and documentation, it appears to be the appropriate answer but I am having trouble figuring out how to get to work with `NSInvocationOperation` and `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`. I can certainly get the `NSError`s out of the `newListResponseForProductID:` method by changing it to something like this:

```
- (StoreDataListResponse *)newListResponseForProductID:(NSString *)productID error:(NSError **)error;
```

How do I get the error generated back into the main thread so I can deal with the failed request?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to run any code on the main thread is to use GCD and blocks on iOS 4 and above. Like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    // Your code to run on the main thread here, 
    // any variables in scope like NSError is captured.
});
```

Or use `dispatch_sync()` if you know you are on a background thread and want the block to complete on the main thread before you continue.

Comment: Using `dispatch_sync()` is a great way to deadlock your app;  if the main queue has `dispatch_sync()`d to your background queue, for example.